# redirect browser window from expressjs after qr code authentication request made from android phone

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, socket.io, qr-code

1. Android app was developed using ionic framework.
2. I have an **authenticated user** on my android phone using **jwt token** stored in local storage.
3. I have a web application which authenticates user when they scan the qr code from their android app.
4. On successfull scan from the android phone.I make an ajax call to the server with **jwt token (set on req.headers.authorization using $httpProvider)** and **qr scanned code.**

> Android(Ionic Framework) app ajax call code

```
$scope.scanqr = function () {
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function (result) {
      $http({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/',
        method:'POST',
        data:{
          //qr code result.text
          unique: result.text
        }
      })
        .success(function () {
          alert("Authenticated in WebApp");
        });
    },
    function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed.Try Again");
    }
  );
};
```

> Server Code running on http://localhost:3000/ This is the route in which I receive the request and process it.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.body.unique) {
        Code.findOne({
            unique:req.body.unique
        }, function (err,code) {
            if(code){
                var query = Code.remove({unique: req.body.unique});
                query.exec();
                var token = req.headers.authorization;
                req.session.token = token;
                res.cookie('auth',token);
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            }else{
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

I know that redirection doesn't happen because the request was made by the phone not by the browser.Is there any way to redirect the browser ?

> I tried **socket.io** by emitting the token and saving it in browsers local storage.But the drawback is that I'm emitting the token to **everyone**.If multiple browsers were opened with the webapp all the windows are authenticated and I cannot emit to a particular browser also as I do not know any details of the requestor.
>
> Are there any possible solutions for this problem ?